# Efficient way of Calling external functions Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

Which is the computationally efficient way to call external functions. i.e in other folder.

> *Calling a Function Using Its Handle* OR *userpath Folder on the Search Path*

Second one is simple like `addpath('../folder_x/');` but I have confusion with the first one, [Calling Function using its Handle](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/calling-a-function-using-its-handle.html), How to spectify *folder_x* in this case?

```
fHandle = @myFun;
[out1, out2, ...] = fHandle(in1, in2, ...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add a function to your search path using a function handle. In your example `myFun` is a already known function. Use `addpath`

Comment: Then what is the difference between both, Handles uses `@` and other one simple.

Comment: Both are two totally different concepts. A handle could for example be passed to another function. You could add your function `f3` to your search path using `addpath`, then you could pass it to a function like `integral` using a function handle: `integral(@f3,1,3)`.